# Defining a structure within a local class and initializing it

Tags: c++

Professor at our college gave us a tricky question in which we have to declare a class within a function and structure within that class and then call the function from main(). I tried the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void fun()
{
    class Test
    {
        public:
        struct X
        {
            int v;
        }x;
        x.v=10;
        void method(void) {
            cout << "Local Class called, v="<<x.v;
        }
    };
    Test t;
    t.method();
}
int main(void)
{
    fun();
    return 0;
}
```

But using ideone compiler (C++ 4.9.2), it returns the following error:

> prog.cpp: In function 'void fun()': prog.cpp: 17:5: error: 'x' does not name a type x.v=10; ^

Could anyone please elaborate the problem? I tried using X::x.v but that didn't work too.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the way in which this is a "trick question"? And properly indent your code.

Comment: I suppose declare a class within a function and structure within that class seems to be a bad programming style. And hence, tricky?

Comment: Ah, "tricky" != "trick". :)

Comment: Sorry, English isn't my first language. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You put the assignment `x.v=10;` at class scope, but only declarations and function definitions can live there. That code must go in a function, probably a constructor for `Test`:

```
#include <iostream>

void fun()  
{
   class Test 
   {
   public:
      struct X
      {
         int v;
      } x;

      Test()
      {
         x.v = 10;
      }

      void method()
      {
         std::cout << "Local class called; v = " << x.v << std::endl;
      }
   };

   Test t;
   t.method();  
}

int main()
{
   fun();
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b487d4a4d584519))

Comment: Depending on the C++ version, initializations [may be done on the same line that members are declared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization).